# How to print specific lines of .py file in powershell

Tags: python, python-3.x, powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

lets say I have a python file with the instructions

```
print("hello")
print("hello1")
```

I can run the python file in powershell by doing >python something.py, but how would I execute a command that is on a specific line that is in the something.py file.

Basically, how would I just show the result of print("hello1") in powershell, which is on line 2 of something.py.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Save that specific line to a separate file and then run it using python:

```
(Get-Content something.py)[1] > one-line.py
python one-line.py
```

This will save the second line (0 based indexing) of something.py to one-line.py and then you can run that as a separate program.

Or you can do it without an intermediate file:

```
$line = (Get-Content scratch.py)[1]; python -c $line
```

Comment: I don't know how you do piping/redirection in powershell, but you *could* use `python -c <source code string>` instead of using an intermediate file

Comment: thanks, updated the answer to do it without an extra file